# VBA+VBS SendKey Script

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I am working on automating the upload process of multiple files to a website. For that, the user has to click on the Browse button and the select the file and hit on Open.

The same thing I try to replicate using VBA and VBS since the moment the "Choose file to upload" box appears, the VBA code is stuck
So, using VBA I create a VBS file that runs before the upload file box appears and adds the filename to the input box and then hits ENTER

```
Public Sub CompleteUploadThread(ByVal fName As String)
    Dim strScript As String, sFileName As String, wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    '---Create VBscript String---
    strScript = "WScript.Sleep 1500" & vbCrLf & _
                "Dim wsh" & vbCrLf & _
                "Set wsh = CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"")" & vbCrLf & _
                "wsh.SendKeys """ & Trim(fName) & """" & vbCrLf & _
                "WScript.Sleep 500" & vbCrLf & _
                "wsh.SendKeys ""{ENTER}""" & vbCrLf & _
                "WScript.Sleep 500" & vbCrLf & _
                "Set wsh = Nothing"
    '---Save the VBscript String to file---
    sFileName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path & "\Authorized\zz_automation.vbs"
    Open sFileName For Output As #1
    Print #1, strScript
    Close #1
    '---Execute the VBscript file asynchronously---
    wsh.run """" & sFileName & """"

    Set wsh = Nothing
End Sub
```

Everything works fine up to pasting the filename, click on Open and closing the dialog box. Once the dialog box is closed, VBA needs to click on a **Continue** button that should trigger the upload process
Once the Continue button is clicked, the pasted text disappears and nothing is uploaded

If I do the same process manually, it will work so I guess that it has to be related to the Sendkeys doing something strange

Could someone help me sort this out?

Below, please find the part of VBA where I use the function mentioned above:

```
CompleteUploadThread el
'el is the filename and path

'click on the Browse button
Call Doc.parentWindow.execScript("document.getElementsByName('filename')[0].click();", "JavaScript")

Dim oHTML_Element As HTMLDDElement   
For Each oHTML_Element In Doc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next
```

The complete page source:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>File Upload</title>


<h3>File Upload</h3>

<div class="indent20">

<form method="post"
      action="process_upload_case.jsp"
      name="dform"
      enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      onsubmit="return checkForm();">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="eoEata" />
<input type="hidden" name="n" value="99999999" />
<input type="hidden" name="appid" value="999" />
<table class="boundedForm alignTop">
<tr>
  <th>Case</th>
  <td>14792562</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>File Description<br/></th>
  <td><textarea name="comments" rows="5" cols="40" style="width:350px;"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Select File</th>
  <td><input type="file" name="filename" size="45" multiple /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">
  <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="reset(); window.close();" />
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function checkForm()
  {
  var f = document.dform;

  var ret = true;

  if (f.filename.value == '')
    {
    alert('Error: No file selected.');
    ret = false;
    }

  if (f.comments.value.length > 500 )
    {
    alert('Error: Description too long.' );
    ret = false;
    }

  return(ret);
  }

function reset()
{
var f = document.dform;
f.filename.value = '';
f.comments.value = '';
return true;
}
-->
</script>
```

Comment: as an aside you can remove that end loop and use doc.querySelector("input[type=submit]"

Comment: what single action currently is not working?

Comment: Clicking on the submit button triggers the deletion of the filepath in the filename input

Comment: have you considered doing the whole thing with ie or selenium?

Comment: The browser used is IE. Not sure about selenium, and how to manage it

Comment: Is it a private/login based url?

Comment: Yes, it's protected

Comment: I don't think that is the complete page html if you were to go to the page and right click inspect > then select the html opening tag element and right click copy html that should give the entire html which would end with the html closing tag of </html>

Answer (score 0):

When you click the "submit" button, perhaps you need to call some js as well, or fireevent? Hard to tell without seeing page source.

Comment: posting the page source in couple of seconds

Comment: the idea is that, clicking the submit button deletes the filename content